# Not able to convert err into go-sqlite3.Error

Tags: go, go-sqlite3

[image: t]

I am trying to convert an err in Go to go-sqlite3.Error, but it fails always.
Above image represents the snapshot of my debug windows, which shows that the err is of type go-sqlite3.Error

I am using below code to type cast.

```
import (
    "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)

if err != nil {
    if sqlite3Err, ok := err.(*sqlite3.Error); ok {
        if sqlite3Err.Code == sqlite3.ErrConstraint && sqlite3Err.ExtendedCode == 1555 {
            // SQLITE3 ERROR 1555 : PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT ERROR
            return errors.New("Log Error")
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you see if you print its type? `fmt.Printf("%T", err)`?

Comment: There are no type casts in Go. What your code tries to do is a type assertion. If this tape assertion fails it means you botched up the types. You should read the documentation of the function which returns your error and take a close look at its signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following example. `err.(*sqlite3.Error)` is changed to `err.(sqlite3.Error)`

```
if sqlite3Err, ok := err.(sqlite3.Error); ok {
    if sqlite3Err.Code == sqlite3.ErrConstraint &&
        sqlite3Err.ExtendedCode == 1555 {
        // logic 
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for posting this answer. It works!!!!

Comment: @AshishMittal :)